# Looking for sources: Graph search in social media

Tags: graphs

I am looking for more information/references on how graph search is utilized in social media. Papers, books , anything really.

Comment: This seems extremely broad. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: For example, facebook has hyped up the upcoming facebook graph search. Where can I find more technical details about it? (Unfortunately, that's as specific as my professor was when he gave me the task)

Comment: If Facebook hasn't released technical information about its own service, it's unlikely that anyone else has!

Comment: Indeed. In a more general sense though, is there any established graph-search method on social platforms?(e.g for suggesting friends etc.)

Comment: agree literal question is too broad, but think this is not too broad with the clarifications in comments. am answering question based on asker's comments that relate it to the Facebook graph search feature & also that there is not too much general published research on the specific topic/capability (ie combined semantic/social network searching).

Comment: @vzn Thanks for taking the time to answer anyway!

Comment: Use Google Scholar. Read a bunch of abstracts. Select a handful of articles to read more closely. Post more specific questions. Note that the professor gave you the task to *learn how to do this kind of research*, not to get the facts/answers. (For reference: this is not only too broad, by the OPs explanation it's also a problem dump.)

Comment: Well I started asking around exactly because the question is too broad and brute forcing google scholar pages turned out to be impractical. User "vzn" for example provided some useful information. Just to clarify, I didn't come here to get someone to do the work for me. I was just looking for pointers to narrow down my list of options from people who are probably more knowledgable on the subject. I guess that kind of question isn't suitable for this site though(?).

Comment: ***strongly object to (unilateral) closing questions as "too broad" with none or only few answers & also this question was specifically narrowed by questioner in response to feedback in comments***

Comment: FWIW, I just accepted your answer since you were the only one with enough common sense to get straight to the point. Editing the post and spending even more time on those details probably defeats my purpose of coming here in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Facebook graph search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Graph_Search) is a relatively new technology pioneered/announced by Facebook that attempts to search for relevant info based on social connections in a social media system (eg Facebook). ie it finds relevant info based on exploring information "nearby" on the ["social graph"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_graph).

in this way, basically every person on Facebook doing the same search with same search terms might come up with different results based on how it interrelates with what their friends are posting about. this also can be seen as part of a trend where the major online services are encroaching on each others prior territory, eg Google's recent introduction of Google+ social network. conversely Facebook is now encroaching on Google's lucrative and highly-developed search engine technology.

there is a huge amount of media coverage [cited in the wikipedia article] but mainly at a superficial level of a product introduction. in contrast to [Googles pagerank algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagerank), the Facebook algorithm did not appear to originate in open scientific research, but instead is a mostly proprietary technology developed within Facebook. Facebook is not going to want to release many details, but the following is useful for an overview, written by Xiao Li, an engineering manager on the natural language team for Graph Search, and Maxime Boucher a research scientist for Graph Search.

- [Under the Hood: The natural language interface of Graph Search](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-the-natural-language-interface-of-graph-search/10151432733048920)

also it will be natural for Facebook to insinuate this algorithm as highly developed and competitive with Pagerank but because its in early stages of development, one would not expect highly advanced results competitive with Pagerank at least at first (because Pagerank has been highly developed over a decade etc) *with respect to mere semantic capability*. on the other hand Facebook has access to a social graph, and it would be expected to prove superior quality in some types of searches that best leverage/focus on ones personal social network.

there does not appear to be much open scientific research *outside of Facebook* related to this topic. however the following seems to be a publication of some of the principles in a previous prototype/experimental iteration/version called Unicorn which the new feature is probably originating from/growing out of.

- [Unicorn](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2536239): a system for searching the social graph

  > Unicorn is an online, in-memory social graph-aware indexing system designed to search trillions of edges between tens of billions of users and entities on thousands of commodity servers. Unicorn is based on standard concepts in information retrieval, but it includes features to promote results with good social proximity. It also supports queries that require multiple round-trips to leaves in order to retrieve objects that are more than one edge away from source nodes. Unicorn is designed to answer billions of queries per day at latencies in the hundreds of milliseconds, and it serves as an infrastructural building block for Facebook's Graph Search product. In this paper, we describe the data model and query language supported by Unicorn. We also describe its evolution as it became the primary backend for Facebook's search offerings.